# Issues with Reverse DNS Lookup for HTTPS on Squid Logging

Tags: squid

I am having issue with reverse dns lookups with squid, I am using wccp redirecting https connections to a squid proxy server. I am also using squidguard for content filter. When the https traffic arrives at the proxy it is already been through the dns lookup process and is https so I can not see the SNI information. So the server only see the ip address of the site. This is causing issues with the Black List of the content filter as it uses fqdn. Has anyone had experience with setting squid to allow for reverse lookups for https traffic. I do not want to use MITM.

Logs

```
1510234383.852  10522 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 145 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x 
1510234383.852  10571 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 145 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234383.852  10639 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 145 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234383.959    106 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 482 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234384.358    268 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5195 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234384.421   5482 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 780 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234386.893     25 x.x.100.21 TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1510234386.893     25 x.x.100.21 TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1510234386.893     25 x.x.100.21 TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1510234386.963    108 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 482 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234387.942  10081 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3573 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
1510234387.978  10117 x.x.100.21 TCP_TUNNEL/200 156 CONNECT x.x.x.x:443 - ORIGINAL_DST/x.x.x.x -
```

Config

```
acl localnet src x.x.x.x/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src x.x.x.x/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src x.x.x.x/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src xxxx::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src xxxx::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128

http_port 8080 intercept
wccp2_router x.x.120.254
wccp2_forwarding_method gre
wccp2_return_method gre
wccp2_service standard 0
#
https_port 8081 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/opt/squid_certs/proxyCAnew.pem
ssl_bump none all
sslcrtd_program /lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /lib64/squid/ssl_db -M 40MB
sslcrtd_children 10
wccp2_router x.x.120.254
wccp2_forwarding_method gre
wccp2_return_method gre
wccp2_service dynamic 70
wccp2_service_info 70 protocol=tcp flags=dst_ip_hash priority=240 ports=443
wccp2_assignment_method hash

log_fqdn on

always_direct allow all

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

url_rewrite_program /usr/bin/squidGuard -c /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf
```

Comment: Please fix the (terrible) formatting of your question.. All it takes is to use the "{}" button of the editor. Let me know (via an extra comment) when you're done and I'll remove my downvote ...

Comment: Formatting has been modified, Thank you for the information.

Comment: merci for taking my advice!